# Android EditText value not changing on button click

Tags: java, android

I have the following code, which should change the value of an `EditText` field when the button is clicked...

```
public class ConvertActivity extends Activity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        final Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1);
        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                b1.setEnabled(true);

                EditText editText2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
                String editTextStr2 = editText2.getText().toString();

                editText2.setText("empty");
    }
        });
    }
}
```

However, when I click the button, the text doesn't change. Is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: Have you any error like 'ResourceNotFoundException'

Comment: I am not getting any errors it is simply not changing the empty edittext2 box from "" to "empty"

Comment: what does `m.getND()` returns? this is what you put in your `editText2`

Comment: which value you pass in getND() and getNH?

Comment: m.getND() maybe returns empty string "", so you don't register change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

comment out the line

```
editText2.setText(m.getND());
```

and see if it set editText2 to "empty" - my guess is m.getND() is returning null

Comment: that did it. Forgot about that empty string.

Answer (score 1):

You are **enabling the button in onClick of that button**...that means it doesn't function i think.. because earlier it was not enabled..put

```
b1.setEnabled(true);
```

in onCreate part.. not in onClick..

Comment: chances are the button is already enabled, as it is by default

Comment: yes...you may be right.. but his comment " not changing the empty edittext2 box from "" to "empty""... and he is trying to put it in onClick only... i think he must have disabled it in xml... because i don't see any reason why should enable it..

Comment: neither do I. but that would be weird